# No puedo abrir SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Estoy instalando SQL Server, pero me aparace un error al abrirlo.
¿Qué puedo hacer?

[image: Eror]

Comment: Tal y como está ahora, la pregunta es un poco amplia (no hay mucha información con la que trabajar). Deberías comprobar los logs y añadir más información (o si te dice qué componente es el que falla, probar a reinstalarlo)

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no es sobre programación

Answer (score 2):

Tal cual lo dice el mensaje, uno o mas elementos necesarios para iniciar la aplicación están dañados, o fueron borrados, o no se encuentran en las carpetas que deberían.

La solución rápida sería reinstalar SQL Server Management Studio, te llevará menos tiempo que buscar aquellos componentes que faltan o están dañados.

Si estás instalando desde una unidad externa (USB, CD, HDD o alguna unidad de red) te recomiendo que primero pases los archivos de instalación a tu equipo directamente, esto para evitar errores por si se llegan a desconectar y justo pueda pasar lo mismo que te muestra el mensaje que pusiste.